# Mat-Table from angular materials not displaying data from firebase

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using **Angular**, **NgRedux** and **firebase** (real time database). I'm trying to display my fetched data into a mat-table from Angular/material. I can see the data in the console, but not in the table. I can only display my local data in the table as you can see in my *events.component.html* temple down bellow.

I'm quite new with Angular. Any help will be highly appreciated.

> **here is my *events.component.ts* file**

```
import { NgRedux } from '@angular-redux/store';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Event } from '../entities/Event';
import { EventeActions } from '../store/actions/EventAcitons';
import { AppState } from '../store/Store';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-events',
  templateUrl: './events.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./events.component.scss']
})
export class EventsComponent implements OnInit{
  public events: Event[];

  private availableEvents: Event[] = [
    { 
      event: 'Picnic', 
      date: '12/02/2021', 
      location: 'Rådhusstrædet', 
      status: 'published' 
    },
    { 
      event: 'Surfing', 
      date: '11/04/2021', 
      location: 'København V', 
      status : 'draft' 
    },
  ];

  displayedColums = ['event', 'date', 'location', 'status'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Event>();

  getAvailableEvents() {
    return this.availableEvents.slice();
  }

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private ngRedux: NgRedux<AppState>,
    private eventActions: EventeActions
    ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.eventActions.readEvent();

    //  this.dataSource.data = this.getAvailableEvents();

    this.ngRedux.select(state => state.events).subscribe(res => {
      this.events = res.events;
    })

    
  }

  editPost(id: any) {
    this.router.navigate(['neweditevent', {myId: id}])
  }

}
```

> **and here is my events.component.html file**

```
<h1 class="title">Planned Events</h1>
<div class="flexHeader">
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" routerLink="/neweditevent" id="newEditBtn">New Event</button>
</div>
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  
    <ng-container matColumnDef="event">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Event </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.event}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
    <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Date </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.date | date}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
    <ng-container matColumnDef="location">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Location </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.location}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
    <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Status </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.status}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColums"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColums;"></tr>
  </table>
```

Thank you in advance...

Comment: the this.dataSource.data is the assignment to the table, so whatever the response is from your api it should be assigned to that. Ex. this.datasource.data = <responseObject>  Also assuming your response object is similar to your availableEvents local object.

Comment: Hey Brian, thank for reaching out. I still don't get how I should assigne the response to the Api. I tried to do : this.datasource.data = this.events, but still doesn't work and I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

Comment: under the line where you have this.events = res.events;. Try adding the dataSource.data  assignement there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
ngOnInit(): void {
 this.eventActions.readEvent();

 //  this.dataSource.data = this.getAvailableEvents();

 this.ngRedux.select(state => state.events).subscribe(res => {
   this.events = res.events;
   this.dataSource.data = this.events;
 })
}
```